# How to iterate and export all tables in a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Our tests traces are written into a SQL Server database such that every test gets it's own table: `log_table_<test_name>`.

All the traces are written into the same database.

Is there anyway to iterate over all the tables and export each of them to file via C#?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Getting all table names? Writing them to a file? Handling the format? For each of those an answer can be found on SO.

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't know how to iterate over all the tables in the DB without knowing the table names in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fire a query over [`tables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224(v=sql.120).aspx) and you will get all tables that match your test table name format:

```
select *
from   information_schema.tables
where  table_name like 'log_table_%'
```

Another option is to use `sys.all_objects`:

```
select *
from   sys.all_objects
where  type = 'U'
and    name like 'log_table_%'
```

You can check the columns returned in the data set, or check the `information_schema.columns` or `sys.all_columns` view for the column names.

Comment: Can I tell from the result which record belongs to which table?

Comment: No, you have to go over those tables again to get the result. You can check the columns returned in the data set, or check the `information_schema.columns` view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SqlConnection.GetSchema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136366(v=vs.110).aspx) method to retrieve all the tables such as the following

```
sqlConnection.Open();
DataTable tables = sqlConnection.GetSchema("Tables");
sqlConnection.Close();
```

kindly note that the returned data table contains both tables and views however there is a column table_type, which tells you whether it's a VIEW or a BASE TABLE.